# PXSelector for custom table not changing records when selecting different record

Tags: acumatica

I have been trying to get this to work and have been unsuccessful. I've customized dozens of existing pages and used selectors for existing database tables, but cannot get a selector to work for a Maint page for custom table.

I made a custom page with a form on it and am trying to add a selector using the CD as the display. From reading the documentation and comparing to other out of the box pages, this is what I came up with.

In my database my ID field is my PK and auto-increment int not null, CD is just a nvarchar(10) not null

Here is the ID and CD in my DAC:

```
    #region ID
    [PXDBIdentity()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "ID")]
    public Int32? ID { get; set; }
    public class iD : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region DesignCD
    [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(UsrDesign.iD), SubstituteKey = typeof(UsrDesign.designCD))]
    public string DesignCD { get; set; }
    public class designCD : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
```

I can toggle between records using the prev and next buttons and everything works great, but when using the selector it does not change records. I have tried commit changes = true and every other variant I could think of.

Can someone please help solve this seemingly stupid question?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, did you try setting the ID as key?

Comment: Yes, tried using the ID, tried not having an ID at all and just using the CD as the primary. I have a case open with Acumatica, so once I get a working response from them I will update the thread.

Comment: Hmm, Actually i too raised a case that time and what i answered below is the workaround they gave us. I believe it was in v4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my scenario, the issue with the selector was being caused by using the same DataMember on the form as well as the tab on the page. I don't quite understand why that's an issue, but creating an alternate view PXSelect>> CurrentDesign and assigned the tab that view solves the issue.

Hope this will help someone else in the future that might make the same mistake.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Upvoted your answer today.  Your note about using the same View for the DataMember for the Form and Tab controls is what solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using the Identity field and i couldnt get a proper solution in this.

What we did was, we removed the identity property both from db and dac 
//[PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)]

and in the row persisting event we manually generated the next ID if the ID is null

```
protected virtual void ROW_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row == null) return;

            ROW Doc = (ROW)e.Row;
            if ((e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) == PXDBOperation.Insert)
            {
                 ROW LastDoc = new ROW();
                if (Doc.ID == null || Doc.ID.Equals("<NEW>"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        LastDoc = (ROW)PXSelectGroupBy<ROW, Aggregate<Max<ROW.ID>>>.Select(this);
                    }
                    catch { }
                    if (LastDoc != null)
                    {
                        if (LastDoc.ID != null)
                            Doc.ID = LastDoc.ID + 1;
                        else
                            Doc.ID = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

I dont know the exact reason of this problem, but this is the way we solved it. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

Since the selector attribute is attached to the CD property, try changing the `iD` in its definition to `designCD`, it should work:

`[PXSelector(typeof(UsrDesign.designCD), SubstituteKey = typeof(UsrDesign.designCD))]`

Answer (score 0):

This post saved me today.

I went over my ID field at least a hundred times, verifying each field of the DAC relentlessly.  No matter what I did, using the selector to navigate to the record did not do anything.  The TRACE just showed "CANCEL" as the action taken on the form.

My .aspx form consists of a summary section and a tab section. I was using the same View for the DataMemeber for the Form and Tab elements of the page.

Just added a second View and set the Tab's DataMember value to the new View.

By adding another view, this is what I mean:

```
public SelectFrom<MyDAC>.View Request;

public SelectFrom<MyDAC>
        .Where<MyDAC.requestID.IsEqual<MyDAC.requestID.FromCurrent>>.View CurrentRequest;
```

"Request" was my original View and "CurrentRequest" is the additional View.

Feels a bit weird to do it this way, so I imagine I don't have the .aspx page set up 100% correctly then.  I may dig into that and see why this is an issue.